# find position of row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i m imaging how i can achieve below scenarios in mysql using query. let me show  table structure

```
 id| agentid | value 
  1|  1      | "testing value" 
  2|  1      | "testing value1" 
  3|  2      | "testing value2" 
  4|  2      | "testing value3" 
  5|  1      | "testing value4"
```

below thing i want to achieve

```
    id| agentid | value            | position
     1|  10     | "testing value"  |  1
     2|  10     | "testing value1" |  2
     3|  20     | "testing value2" |  1
     4|  20     | "testing value3" |  2
     5|  10     | "testing value4" |  3
```

let me explain i want first row in position in first, 2 row in 2 position and so on but if new agentid appears then it  position should be 1 ....

Comment: You could just select all that have the same `agentid` value, then iteratively assign your `position` value from there. Repeat for each unique `agentid` value/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by agentid order by id) as position
from t
order by t.id;
```

This has been available in MySQL since version 8 was released.

In earlier versions, you can use a correlated subquery or variables.  It is quite possible that the correlated subquery will have decent performance:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.agentid = t.agentid and t2.id <= t.id
       )
from t;
```

You want an index on `(agentid, id)` for performance.

Comment: it posible to achieve in 7 verison mysql

Comment: Are you talking about MySQL 7 ? @Tanmay , the new MySQL was so fine that MySQL devs skipped MySQL 6 and MySQL 7 and directly go to MySQL 8 instead..